# Estou tentando construir um gerador de apostas da Megasena com os seguintes parâmetros

Tags: php

eu estou tentando construir um gerador de apostas da mega sena com os seguintes parâmetros:

quantidade de dezenas e quantidade de jogos

Regras:

1. Os números não podem se duplicar entre os jogos.
2. Considerar as dezenas entre 00 e 59.

Saída final:

```
  1 - Lista de jogos  
  2 - Lista de números que se repetiram mais de uma vez
```

Ex: Considerando parâmetros quantidade dezenas = 7 e jogos = 2

Saída:

```
      3 - 5 - 7 - 9 - 20 - 55 - 56
      5 - 20-51 - 55 -56-  57 - 59

 Duplicados: 

    55 - 2x        
     5 - 2x
```

eis o código que eu construí até agora:

```
<?php

function getRandomNumbers($num, $min, $max, $repeat = false, $sort = false)
{
    if ((($max - $min) + 1) >= $num) {
        $numbers = array();

        while (count($numbers) < $num) {
            $number = mt_rand($min, $max);

            if ($repeat || !in_array($number, $numbers)) {
                $numbers[] = $number;
            }
        }

        switch ($sort) {
        case SORT_ASC:
            sort($numbers);
            break;
        case SORT_DESC:
            rsort($numbers);
            break;
        }

        return $numbers;
    }

    return false;
}

?>

<?php

if ($numbers = getRandomNumbers(6, 1, 60, false, SORT_ASC)) {
    print implode(', ', $numbers);
} else {
    print 'A faixa de valores entre $min e $max deve ser igual ou superior à' .
        ' quantidade de números requisitados';
}

?>
```

porém não consigo implementar as condições de restrição, podem auxiliar por favor?

Comment: Os jogos são sempre 7 números?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não pode repetir entre eles seria mais fácil definir quais são as escolhas possíveis, então:

```
$NumerosDiposniveis = range(0, 59);
```

Quando selecionar um deles, então execute:

```
unset($NumerosDisponiveis[$IndexQueFoiGerado]);
```

---

Basicamente isso:

```
function gerarCombinacao($QntDezenas, &$NumerosDisponiveis){

    $QntDisponivel = count($NumerosDisponiveis);

    if($QntDisponivel < $QntDezenas){
        return false;
    }

    for($n = 0; $n < $QntDezenas; $n++){

        $EscolhaAleatoria = random_int(0, $QntDisponivel - ($n + 1));

        $NumerosDisponiveis = array_values($NumerosDisponiveis);

        $Combinacao[] = str_pad($NumerosDisponiveis[$EscolhaAleatoria], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        unset($NumerosDisponiveis[$EscolhaAleatoria]);

    }

    return implode('-', $Combinacao);

}
```

Então poderia executar:

```
$NumerosDisponiveis = range(0, 59);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo gerarCombinacao(6, $NumerosDisponiveis) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58cd4d1e76429e12f91817977049438fb7f114e9)**

No caso esse é o máximo de números que podem ser gerado, não é possível gerar mais de 10 porque não pode repetir os números segundo você em:

> 1 - Os números não podem se duplicar entre os jogos

Comment: esse resolveu o que eu precisava, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como os números não podem se repetir entre os cartões outra forma de fazer isso é gerar todos os números possíveis (0 a 59) embaralha-los e gerar o número máximo de cartões com sete números, nesse caso são oito. No final você pode escolher quais cartões vai exibir ou manipular.

O ponto chave dessa solução é o `array_chunk()` que quebra o array de números disponíveis por tamanho (7 elementos) e gera assim os cartões. `array_pop()` é responsavel por eliminar o último cartão já que ele possui apenas 4 elmentos.

**[Exemplo - idoene](http://ideone.com/UB9PSf)**

```
<?php

function gerarCartao(){
   $numeros = range(0, 59);
   shuffle($numeros);
   $cartoes = array();

   $cartoes = array_chunk($numeros, 7);
   array_pop($cartoes);
   return $cartoes;

}


print_r(gerarCartao());
```

A saida é algo como:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 32 [1] => 55 [2] => 22 [3] => 53 [4] => 16 [5] => 38 [6] => 49 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 44 [1] => 27 [2] => 28 [3] => 25 [4] => 47 [5] => 14 [6] => 48 )
```